# Interpolation with <Link> of react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working with [react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router), and actually what I want is very simple, so I won't be too long, is just to get a string with a `<Link>` of `react-router` interpolated like:

```
const link = (
  <Link to={"/terms"}>{"terms"}</Link>
);

const label = (
  `something ${link}`
);
```

Actual result:

```
something [object Object]
```

Expected result:

```
something <a href="/terms">terms</a>
```

Anybody knows how do I get the expected result?

Comment: You get an [object Object] because the JSX gets transpiled into a javascript object and not the html. The only way seems to be creating the label manually.

Comment: do you know if there's a way to convert `<Link>` into the HTML tag?

Comment: Atm it sounds like an X-Y problem. You better explain the original issue you're solving, since the provided answer is awful.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and couldn't find a way to evaluate the Link object toString, within an interpolation; however, I found a workaround as (based on your setup) you can pass in multiple nodes in JSX as props. As an example, you could do something like:

```
label={
   <div>
      <span>something</span>
      <Link to={'/terms'}>terms of use</Link>
      <span> and other terms and such</span>
   </div>
}
```

The link could then evaluate to the string/html output you are looking to render. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-to-html

Otherwise, you can use [jsx-transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-transform) package which will give you information regarding the props you are passing.

```
const linkString = jsx.fromString(link, { factory: 'mercury.h' });
console.log(linkString); // 'Link({to: "/terms"}, ["terms"])'
```

Then you can use regex:

```
const linkPath = eval(linkString.match(/{(.*?)}/)[0]); // '/terms'
const label = `<a href="{linkPath}">Whatever</a>`;
```